# SignalR WebSocketServerUrl not null

Tags: asp.net, websocket, signalr

When negotiating with SignalR server, we usually get a null value for the WebSocketServerUrl member of the response. Can someone from SignalR team explain what is the actual meaning of that and under what conditions we do get a value for that member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's deprecated and is never used. The original intent was to be able to run a separate websocket server using SignalR (Like fleck https://github.com/davidfowl/SignalR.Fleck).